# What is the probability of choosing a white ball again

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I am struggling with the math conditional probability task:

There are two boxes. One has 14 white and 32 black balls, another has 23 white and 43 black balls. Choosing a box randomly, we choose a white ball. What is a probability, that from the same box we will choose a white ball again?

My solution:

In general, there are 46 balls in the first box, and 66 box in the second one. There is a condition, that we already chose a white ball and we gonna choose from the same box white ball.

So, to choose a ball from the first box again, we have a probability:

$$\frac{14-1}{46-1} \cdot \frac{1}{2}$$

and from the second box:

$$\frac{23-1}{66-1} \cdot \frac{1}{2}$$

I know, that If I sum these two probabilities the result will be wrong because I did not specify a condition. I believe I need to use Bayes' theorem.

Thus:
$$P(A \mid B) = \frac{P(A~\text{and}~B)}{P(B)}$$
A is event of choosing a white ball again from the same box knowing that B is true (B = firstly we chose a white ball from the random box)

$$P(A~\text{and}~B) = P(A) \cdot P(B)$$

Then we have:
$$\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{P(\text{Probability of choosing a white ball})}{P(\text{Probability of choosing a white ball in general})}$$

I am getting a wrong result and I am struggling with the correctness of my solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We wish to find the probability that a second white ball is selected from the same box given that a white ball has been selected from one of the boxes.

Let $F$ be the probability that a white ball is selected from one of the boxes.  Then
$$\Pr(F) = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{14}{46} + \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{23}{66}$$

Let $E$ be the event that a second white ball is selected from the same box.  Then
$$\Pr(E \cap F) = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{14}{46} \cdot \frac{13}{45} + \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{23}{66} \cdot \frac{22}{65}$$

Hence,
\begin{align*}
\Pr(E \mid F) & = \frac{\Pr(E \cap F)}{\Pr(F)}\\
              & = \frac{\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{14}{46} \cdot \frac{13}{45} + \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{23}{66} \cdot \frac{22}{65}}{\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{14}{46} + \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{23}{66}}
\end{align*}

Comment: From your respone I understood my mistake in my solution. I was wondering why my result was much greater than it had to be. In my calculations I was duplicating values for no purpose. Thank you very muchI clearly just multiplied that having B = Pr(F), which was correct in my calculations, however, P(A and B)  was incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

The probability that the first ball was extracted from the first box is
$$
\text{Probability}_1=\frac{\frac{\binom{14}{1}}{\binom{46}{1}}}{\left(\frac{\binom{14}{1}}{\binom{46}{1}}+\frac{\binom{23}{1}}{\binom{66}{1}}\right)}=
$$
The probability that the first ball was extracted from the second box is
$$
\text{Probability}_2=\frac{\frac{\binom{23}{1}}{\binom{66}{1}}}{\left(\frac{\binom{14}{1}}{\binom{46}{1}}+\frac{\binom{23}{1}}{\binom{66}{1}}\right)}=
$$
What is a probability, that from the same box we will choose a white ball again?
$$
\text{Probability}=\left({{\text{Probability}_1}\cdot\frac{\binom{13}{1}}{\binom{45}{1}}+{\text{Probability}_2}\cdot\frac{\binom{22}{1}}{\binom{65}{1}}}\right)=
$$

Comment: don't you need to divide by $2$?

Comment: thats what I wanted to answer, also, the result should start with 0,3....

Comment: Thus, that should be conditional probability and we are supposed to use Bayes' theorem